# #1052 - Column 'syear' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this SQL will appear this error. 
`#1052 - Column 'syear' in where clause is ambiguous`. any one give me answer.

```
SELECT c.course_id
     , c.TITLE
     , c.SHORT_NAME
     , cs.overallmark 
  FROM courses c
     , course_subjects cs
 WHERE syear = '2010' 
   AND c.subject_id = cs.subject_id 
 ORDER 
    BY c.course_id
     , c.TITLE
     , c.SHORT_NAME
     , cs.overallmark
```

Comment: This means that both thables in your FROM clause have a column named "syear", therefore, to use that column, you have to specify the table's name, as you do with other columns: try with courses.syear or course_subjects.syear.

Comment: One has to wonder why you have such a column in both tables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT c.course_id, c.TITLE, c.SHORT_NAME, cs.overallmark 
FROM courses c JOIN
     course_subjects cs
     ON c.subject_id = cs.subject_id 
WHERE c.syear = 2010 
ORDER BY c.course_id, c.TITLE, c.SHORT_NAME, cs.overallmark;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify all column names, especially when a query references more than one table.
- I assume that `syear` is stored as a number not a string.  Do not put quotes around string constants.

Comment: Was interested in your statement 'Never use commas in the FROM clause', it may be clearer but is there any other reason?

Comment: @NigelRen "clearer" is really reason enough, but besides that; the comma-notation is less powerful and has generally been out of favor for almost two decades. _clearer=easier to read=easier to maintain=less bugs_

Answer (score 1):

You have a column named `syear` in both your tables and the DB engines does not know which one to pick.

Add the table name before it

```
course_subjects.syear
```

Besides that you should not use the old implicit join syntax any more.